# position of animate controls

Tags: tikz-pgf, animate

is there a way to define position of controls of animate control buttons? By default they are centered below the image, I'd like to be able to shift it horizontally.

Comment: Currently, there is no option for controlling the horizontal position. I could try to add one that allows the controls to be left/right aligned or centred. Would that be enough?

Comment: Yes, that would be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:** Version 2020/03/24 is available on CTAN. Option `controlsaligned=...` has been extended:

```
controlsaligned=left[+<indent>] | center | right[+<indent>]
```

> Animation controls are centred below the animation widget by default.
>   With this option one can choose between centred, flush-left or
>   flush-right alignment. The optional `<indent>` inserts additional
>   horizontal space that pushes the control buttons away from the left or
>   right edge of the animation widget towards the opposite side.
>   `<indent>` must be a valid TeX dimension. Negative values may be used,
>   as in `controlsaligned=right+-4em`, in which case control buttons
>   protrude beyond the animation’s right vertical edge by `4em`.

---

New version (2020/03/23) is on the way to CTAN. The new option is

```
controlsaligned=left | center | right
```

Besides centering, it allows the animation controls to be aligned with the left or right edges of the animation widget.

Comment: Thank you very much :)